# Firebase serv functions locally - how to test?

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore

I have spent a few days learning about Firebase functions.
I managed to have a few req res functions deployed.
Testing is a huge pain having to deploy obviously.
I have been on web pages all over on testing locally, and the best I could find from the docs and fb videos are to use:

firebase serve --only functions

This woks for a hello world function.

Questions:

1. But how do you send a payload to a req res function when testing locally?
2. Does that function then use your db served at fb?

I have tried to add a json encoded string but it doesn't work.

If anyone can just show me an example or if I'm missing something, can't find any examples with more local testing content.

Answer (score 0):

This video helped me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=2&ab_channel=Firebase

For some it will seem obvious, but to me it wasn't.

Use firebase serve --only functions, then use POSTMAN to test with your local url.
Pass the body as you would. Works great.